# can i read two values for option at a time using popt library?

Tags: c++, linux

i am writing a sample to read arguments using popt library. my code is given below.

```
enum
{
   INPUT_NAME=1,
   SYMBOL
};
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char filename[ 128 ], symbol[32];
    memset(filename, 0x0, 128);
    memset(symbol, 0x0, 32);

    struct poptOption opttable[] =
    {
        { "file", 'f', POPT_ARG_STRING, filename, INPUT_NAME, "filenames to read", "list of files we need to read" },
        { "symbol", 'r', POPT_ARG_STRING, symbol, SYMBOL, "symbol to view", NULL },
        POPT_AUTOHELP
        POPT_TABLEEND
    };
    poptContext options_socket = poptGetContext( NULL, argc, ( const char **)argv, opttable, 0 );
    int optionvalue(0);
    while( optionvalue > -1 )
    {
        optionvalue = poptGetNextOpt( options_socket );
        if(optionvalue == INPUT_NAME)
        {
           strcpy(filename, poptGetOptArg( options_socket ));
           printf("filename you are giving as input is :%s\n", filename);
        }
        else if( optionvalue == SYMBOL)
        {
           strcpy(symbol, poptGetOptArg( options_socket ));
           printf("symbol you are giving as input is :%s\n", symbol);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

by using this code i am able to read single value for each option. is there any way to get list of values using single option ?

my current program works like this.

```
sample run to my program: ./popt -f file1.txt file2.txt -r symbol1
OUTPUT:
filename you are giving as input is :file1.txt
symbol you are giving as input is :symbol1
DESIRED OUTPUT:
filename you are giving as input is :file1.txt
filename you are giving as input is :file2.txt
symbol you are giving as input is :symbol1
```

is that possible using popt library?

Comment: Not seeing any `C++` here

Comment: this is regarding popt library in linux. I didn't find any popt related keywords. That's why i put c++ and linux key words.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can achieve by using poptGetArgs function.

Comment: This does not seem to work. The first call to poptGetArgs  gets the first argument, the second call gets NULL.